# "Guess the animal" or "Guess what animal it is"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

A child is talking to another child:

> "Hey! Guess what animal it is. It is white and black and has a long neck."

or

> "Hey! Guess the animal. It is white and black and has a long neck."

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct, but the word [*guess*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/guess) is used in different senses:

> **1.** to arrive at or commit oneself to an opinion about (something) without having sufficient evidence to support the opinion fully: *to guess a person's weight.*
>
> **2.** to estimate or conjecture about correctly: *to guess what a word means.*

The examples given are more enlightening than the definitions; you see that the usage of *guess* is correct either like this:

> Guess the animal:

or like this:

> Guess what animal this is:

Comment: In both cases, *guess* has the same meaning; it's just that the two sentences include different ways to use *guess*.  So both meanings are for both sentences.